# PHP - Magento category importer

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to adapt this script, but there is no way to work. I show it as is, imports a txt respecting the hierarchy. I want to do the same, but simply using an array, the hierarchy respects the value of the array key.

**Now**

demo.txt

Fruit (Root category)

- Apples (category)

  - Golden (subcategory)

**What I try to do:**

```
$ array = array (
     '0 '=>' Fruits (Root category) ', 
     '1 '=>' Apples (category) ', 
     '2 '=>' Golden (subcategory) '
);
```

**Code**

```
<?php

// env config
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);

// mage setup
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);


// open the tree file
if (!$handle = fopen("demo.txt", "r"))
    die('Failed to open file');


// process tree
$last_offsets = 0;
$last_item_per_offset = array();
while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) 
{
    $offset = strlen(substr($line, 0, strpos($line,'-')));
    $cat_name = trim(substr($line, $offset+1));

    $category_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                                ->addFieldToFilter('name', $cat_name)
                                ->setPageSize(1);


    if (isset($last_item_per_offset[$offset-1]))
    {
        $category_collection->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', (int)$last_item_per_offset[$offset-1]->getId());
    }

    if ($category_collection->count()) // item exists, move on to next tree item
    {
        $last_item_per_offset[$offset] = $category_collection->getFirstItem();
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        if ($offset-1 == 0 && !isset($last_item_per_offset[$offset-1])) // no root item found
        {
            echo "ERROR: root category not found. Please create the root\n";
        }
        else if(!isset($last_item_per_offset[$offset-1])) // no parent found. something must be wrong in the file
        {
            echo "ERROR: parent item does not exist. Please check your tree file\n";
        }

        $parentitem = $last_item_per_offset[$offset-1];

        // create a new category item
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        $category->setStoreId(0);

        $category->addData(array(
            'name'          => $cat_name,
            'meta_title'    => $cat_name,
            'display_mode'  => Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::DM_PRODUCT,
            'is_active'     => 1,
            'is_anchor'     => 1,
            'path'          => $parentitem->getPath(),
        ));

        try {
            $category->save();
        } catch (Exception $e){
            echo "ERROR: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
            die();
        }

        $last_item_per_offset[$offset] = $category;
        echo "> Created category '{$cat_name}'\n";
    }
}

fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Magmi http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/. 
Saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

use `setData()` instead of `addData()` and need to add `parent category  id`
Here code

```
$category->setData(array(
            'name'          => $cat_name,
            'meta_title'    => $cat_name,
            'display_mode'  => Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::DM_PRODUCT,
            'is_active'     => 1,
            'is_anchor'     => 1,
            'path'          => $parentitem->getPath(),
            'parent_id'  =>$parentCatId,

        ));
```

let me know ,if you will have any issue.